# "Missing required keys" at Check_MK web API call with CURL in Windows

Tags: json, curl, check-mk

I am trying to get info's of host xxx in Check_Mk using this docu: [Command reference](https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/web_api_references.html)

The example call for getting host information looks like this:

```
curl "http://myserver/mysite/check_mk/webapi.py?action=get_host&_username=automation&_secret=myautomationsecret&output_format=python&request_format=python" -d 'request={"hostname":"myserver123"}'
```

Adapted to my credentials etc. I am getting the following error message:

```
{"result": "Check_MK exception: Missing required key(s): hostname", "result_code": 1}
```

I tried all combinations of `"` and `'` that I could think of in the `request` part but always end up with this error. Calls that don't need a `request` part like `get_all_hosts` work just fine so I either I am doing something horribly wrong with the syntax or some other conditions are not met.

Here is an example call from me:

```
curl "https://CMK_SERVER/CMK_SITE/check_mk/webapi.py?action=get_host&_username=AUTO&_secret=ABC" -d 'request={"hostname":"XXX"}'
```

If I don't use any special characters around the `request` part, I get this error:

```
{"result": "Check_MK exception: Failed to parse JSON request: '{hostname:XXX}': Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)", "result_code": 1}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Interestingly, it works just fine in Linux, but not in Windows.

Comment: Single quotes generally only work on Linux. Try `-d "request={\"hostname\":\"myserver123\"}"`.

Comment: @Reino sorry for the very late reply but your comment helped me, it worked! Thanks alot!